# EC2 instance or spare laptop setup as server: which is safer?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

I want to setup a small dev server, and I would like to be able to access it not only from home, but when I'm away from home too.

I have an old laptop that I could use for this purpose, I would just need to change my router to give access from outside. However, I'm a bit wary of doing this as I'm not sure what the security risk of doing this is. Another option would be to rent an Amazon EC2 instance.

Which is safer from a security point of view?

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks for the replies, I'll go with the EC2 instance.

Comment: With respect, this question seems much like asking whether a black or metallic server is less secure.  You can set up a laptop or an EC2 server securely, or insecurely; it's up to you.  Others have written at length on this site, arguing against using laptops as servers, for valid architectural reasons (I'd link, but can't immediately find the article); but that's orthogonal to the question you've asked, which cannot easily, I think, be technically answered.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: Oh, that **is** a lovely article; much kudos to Jeff for putting the case so well, and thanks to you, Iain, for linking it; I hadn't read it before.  That said, I'm off to answer the question by writing my definitive gorilla vs shark combat simulator, in perl.  Or maybe python.  Or, no, perhaps assembler...

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to write it all out again, so go and read "[Desktops As Servers](http://tomoconnor.eu/blogish/desktops-servers/#.UJY9nmmoqYE)".  You can replace Desktops with Laptops, as they're even cheaper built, and not designed for a long duty cycle.

So rent an EC2 instance.  It's a far better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Laptops are easier to steal, Harder to fix, prone to being dropped. If the setup will be important to you and will lose you money if it is not accessible then use a proper solution ie EC2, rackspace, [insert hosting provider here], would be a more suitable solution.